# Copying data from one excel workbook to another

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a code that uses a button click that grabs data from my input workbook and then pastes it in my output workbook. The problem I cant figure out is that my input workbooks name changes by date but they are all in the same naming convention. I want the code to pull the latest date input file and then paste it in the output workbook. I have no idea where to start.. any help is appreciate.

Thanks

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. You'll need to [edit] to make it more clear. When doing so, please remember that we have ZERO information about what you're trying to do other than what you tell us in your question; we can't read your mind to figure out what you're trying to tell us. Please state the problem clearly and **ask a specific question**. See [How do I ask a good question here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips.

Comment: Ok I'm sorry I will try to fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Ken: you ask for too much in a single question. Also "grabs data from my input workbook and then pastes it in my output workbook" could mean anything. However, this is the function I use to solve the first part of your requirement.  The parameters are a folder name and a file template.  It returns the name of the newest file within the folder that matches the template.

```
Function NewestFileName(ByVal Path As String, ByVal FileTemplate As String) As String

  ' * Finds, and returns the name of, the newest file in folder Path with a name
  '   that matches FileTemplate.  Returns "" if no matching file is found.

  ' * Path          Folder in which to search for files
  ' * FileTemplate  File name specification of the file required.  For example:
  '                     MyFile*.xls

  ' 25Jul11  Copied from RiskRegisterControl V43.xls.
  ' 22Nov11  Name changed from NewestFile to NewestFileName to match NextFileName.
  ' 20Apr12  Minor improvements

  Dim FileDateCrnt              As Date
  Dim FileDateNewest            As Date
  Dim FileNameCrnt              As String
  Dim FileNameNewest            As String

  If Right(Path, 1) <> "\" Then
    Path = Path & "\"
  End If

  FileNameCrnt = Dir$(Path & FileTemplate)
  If FileNameCrnt = "" Then
    NewestFileName = ""
    Exit Function
  End If

  FileNameNewest = FileNameCrnt
  FileDateNewest = FileDateTime(Path & FileNameCrnt)
  Do While True
    FileNameCrnt = Dir$
    If FileNameCrnt = "" Then Exit Do
    FileDateCrnt = FileDateTime(Path & FileNameCrnt)
    If FileDateCrnt > FileDateNewest Then
      FileNameNewest = FileNameCrnt
      FileDateNewest = FileDateCrnt
    End If
  Loop

  NewestFileName = FileNameNewest

End Function
```

Comment: I think this is what I'm after... all I'm wanting is for when I push a button on my output excel sheet it copies everything from the most current input sheet and pastes it in the output sheet

Comment: This is a site where programmers help one another develop their skills. No one is likely to code your entire macro for you. Break your requirement into little steps: (1) Find latest workbook, (2) open workbook as `Src`, (3) copy selected worksheet from `Src` to `ThisWorkbook` (4) Close `Src` without Saving changes (5) Link macro to button. I have given you code for step (1). Look up how to open a workbook. You are to vague for me to be sure my step (3) is what you want so clarify your requirement. If my step (3) is correct, look up copying worksheets or use the macro recorder. . .

Comment: Look up steps (4) and (5). If you run into difficulties ask for help one step as a time. You can create your macro yourself if you break it up as I suggest. Happy programming.